# Check if Name row above is the same and add conditions to it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am getting into python and I want to create a script to get an indication of who did what training. The CSV file has a Name Column and a TrainingID column. I want to check if the row above is the same name and a different training ID. I found Pandas doesn't like standard if statements so I would like to know how to fix it.

```
Name, TrainingID
John,1
John,2
Pete,1
James,1
James,2
James,3
Clint,1
Clint,2
Herb,1
Bob,1
```

Above is a shrunk version of the csv file.

I tried this as a funtion but it just spams 'impossible' as the boolean variables don't switch per row but just the first time they find a duplicate name.

Is there any way to make a function that checks if the row above is the same name, and then prints which trainings that person has completed.

```
def klaar():
    dfCh = pd.read_csv("solitude.csv")
    for row in dfCh.iterrows():        
        booleanM = dfCh.duplicated(subset=['nd']).any()
        booleanT = dfCh.duplicated(subset = ['TrainingID']).any()
        if booleanM == True and booleanT == True:
            print("impossible")
        elif booleanM == True and booleanT == False:
            print("+ 1 training")
        if booleanM == False and booleanT == True:
            print("new person")
```

Comment: Are all the names unique?

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output?

Answer (score 4):

You generally want to avoid iterating over dataframe rows, as that's inefficient.

If you want to know which Name did which TrainingID:

```
df.groupby("Name", as_index=False)["TrainingID"].agg(list)
```

```
    Name TrainingID
0    Bob        [1]
1  Clint     [1, 2]
2   Herb        [1]
3  James  [1, 2, 3]
4   John     [1, 2]
5   Pete        [1]
```

---

If you want to know which TraningID is related to which Name:

```
df.groupby("TrainingID", as_index=False)["Name"].agg(list)
```

```
   TrainingID                                   Name
0           1  [John, Pete, James, Clint, Herb, Bob]
1           2                   [John, James, Clint]
2           3                                [James]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just getting into Python, consider holding off on Pandas and learning its way of handling/manipulating data on top of learning Python itself.

The following mimics [e-motta's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78200871/246801) solution with a dict and Python's standard csv reader:

- The input CSV is opened for reading, and the file handler, f, is used to create a new csv.reader.  The reader iterates row-by-row returning a list of strings for each row.
- Calling next(reader) makes reader iterate and return one row, the header, which gets discarded.
- Calling list(reader) reads all remaining rows into a list.

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip header
    data = list(reader)

print(data)
```

data is just a list of lists of strings:

```py
[
    ["John",  "1"],
    ["John",  "2"],
    ["Pete",  "1"],
    ["James", "1"],
    ["James", "2"],
    ["James", "3"],
    ["Clint", "1"],
    ["Clint", "2"],
    ["Herb",  "1"],
    ["Bob",   "1"],
]
```

Thinking about what you want to end up with, knowing who took how many classes, can be accomplished with a dict that keys a student's name to their course ids:

```py
# Want something like:
#   {
#       "Alice":   ["1", "2"     ],
#       "Bob":     ["1"          ],
#       "Charlie": ["1", "2", "3"],
#   }
students: dict[str, list[str]] = {}
```

Then, iterate every row in data.  Check if the name is not already in the dict and add the name and set an empty list (of course ids), then just append each course id to the student's name:

```py
for row in data:
    name, course_id = row

    if name not in students:
        students[name] = []

    students[name].append(course_id)

print(students)
```

students looks like:

```py
{
    "John":  ["1", "2"     ],
    "Pete":  ["1"          ],
    "James": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "Clint": ["1", "2"     ],
    "Herb":  ["1"          ],
    "Bob":   ["1"          ],
}
```

From there you can process the dict to print the names and courses in order of who took the least or most classes.

Start by getting the names in order of the number of courses they took:

```py
def num_courses(name: str) -> int:
    return len(students[name])


names = sorted(students, key=num_courses)
print(names)
```

```py
['Pete', 'Herb', 'Bob', 'John', 'Clint', 'James']
```

If you wanted to sort by courses taken and then by name:

```py
def num_courses_name(name: str) -> tuple[int, str]:
    return (len(students[name]), name)


names = sorted(students, key=num_courses_name)
print(names)
```

```py
['Bob', 'Herb', 'Pete', 'Clint', 'John', 'James']
```

Then iterate over those names and fetch their courses from the dict to print them.  `{x: <10}` means "left-justify the name and pad with up to 10 spaces to the right of it":

```py
for x in names:
    print(f"student: {x:<10} courses: {','.join(students[x])}")
```

```
student: Bob        courses: 1
student: Herb       courses: 1
student: Pete       courses: 1
student: Clint      courses: 1,2
student: John       courses: 1,2
student: James      courses: 1,2,3
```

Once again, from top to bottom:

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip header
    data = list(reader)


students: dict[str, list[str]] = {}
for row in data:
    name, course_id = row

    if name not in students:
        students[name] = []

    students[name].append(course_id)


def num_courses_name(name: str) -> tuple[int, str]:
    return (len(students[name]), name)


names = sorted(students, key=num_courses_name)
for x in names:
    print(f"student: {x:<10} courses: {','.join(students[x])}")
```

Answer (score 0):

"*I want to check if the row above is the same name and a different training ID*"

You can use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and boolean masks:

```
same_name = df['Name'].eq(df['Name'].shift())
diff_id = df['TrainingID'].ne(df['TrainingID'].shift())
df['flag'] = same_name & diff_id
```

Output:

```
    Name  TrainingID   flag
0   John           1  False
1   John           2   True
2   Pete           1  False
3  James           1  False
4  James           2   True
5  James           3   True
6  Clint           1  False
7  Clint           2   True
8   Herb           1  False
9    Bob           1  False
```

Intermediates:

```
    Name  TrainingID  same_name  diff_id   flag
0   John           1      False     True  False
1   John           2       True     True   True
2   Pete           1      False     True  False
3  James           1      False    False  False
4  James           2       True     True   True
5  James           3       True     True   True
6  Clint           1      False     True  False
7  Clint           2       True     True   True
8   Herb           1      False     True  False
9    Bob           1      False    False  False
```

"*who did what training*"

But if you just want to group the Names by TrainingIDs, a simple [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) is enough:

```
df.groupby('TrainingID')['Name'].agg(set)

TrainingID
1    {Clint, James, Herb, Pete, Bob, John}
2                     {John, Clint, James}
3                                  {James}
Name: Name, dtype: object
```